# How can I validate an rspec instance_double as an instance of the doubled class?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In my code, i test that an object is an instance of a particular class, however instance doubles are a class of `RSpec::Mocks::InstanceVerifyingDouble`

a contrived example is...

```
# spec
@double = instance_double Foo
allow(Bar).to receive(:foo).and_return @double

# lib
until Bar.foo.instance_of? Foo
  # logic to test
  if something == true
    Bar.foo = Foo.new
  else
    Bar.foo = nil
  end
end
```

Is there any way to manipulate the rspec double to mock the class?  Or do i need to just return an actual instance of Foo?

**UPDATE**
I mean to mention, they way i am currently getting around the problem, is like this...

```
# spec
allow(Bar).to receive(:foo).and_return Foo.allocate

# lib
if Bar.foo.instance_of? Foo
  # do something
end
```

I am fine with this solution, since initialize on Foo isn't actually executed, but I would prefer to use rspec/doubles for consistency

**UPDATE**
Changed the example to (hopefully) be more clear. I need to test the results of  `something`, VS the results of `Bar.foo`. *Writing contrived examples is difficult :)*

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can just stub `#instance_of?` to return what you want.

```
@double = instance_double Foo
allow(@double).to receive(:instance_of?).with(Foo).and_return(true)
allow(Bar).to receive(:foo).and_return @double
```

Comment: so.. the code that sets what `Bar.foo` returns is want I want to test, not the calling of `instance_of?`... so that will get the test to pass, but it wouldnt test what i want to test

Comment: I'm confused then. I thought this was about setting up the test so it would run the `#do something` code and you could test that. If you're testing the return value of `Bar.foo` why are you stubbing it?

(It might help if you added more to your example, like an assertion you're trying to get to pass and what you want to test).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I thought it worth the comment.

I would recommend a change in the loop structure to use a `break` instead of the condition on the loop itself.  Would make the test much easier.

```
until
  if something == true
    Bar.foo = Foo.new
    break
  end
end
```

This will allow for stubbing `something` with multiple different results until you want it to be true.

```
allow(<whatever>).to receive(:something).and_return(false, 7, 'q', true)
expect(Bar).to receive(:foo=).with(double)
```

If you really want to explicitly call `Bar.foo = nil`, that gives you more power because you can set up the return for `something` and then do a count on how many times you call `Bar.foo=`

```
allow(<whatever>).to receive(:something).and_return(false, 7, 'q', true)
expect(Bar).to receive(:foo=).with(nil).exactly(3).times
expect(Bar).to receive(:foo=).with(double).once
```

Remember in Ruby, `Bar.foo = obj` is really a call to `foo=` not `foo`.